# Does the Cisco SPA range of phones work with CallManager/CME?

Tags: cisco, asterisk, linksys, call-manager

I have about 15 phones and am looking to upgrade from asterisk to an all Cisco solution. Do we need to replace the phones as well?

Comment: I don't know... do you? Your question title makes no sense and your question lacks the appropriate level of detail and information.

Comment: Sorry i missed the operating verb. corrected now. The question is a simple one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have Linksys Phones SPA941 working perfectly with CISCO CME. You might not need to replace the phones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure.  Cisco would be the first port of call if it were me trying to answer it.  The actual point is that you probably should replace the phones too, and go for an *all* cisco solution.  That way you can guarantee with more certainty that any problems you have will be supportable  by your vendor.

Yes, replace the phones.  If you don't, it'll come back and bite you in the ass later on.

Comment: Unfortunately I had a feeling this was the case; I was hoping as they were Cisco branded I could save the money, but I think they are only Cisco in terms of name, and Linksys in terms of soul :(

Comment: I agree that they're probably not going to work. Personally, I think Cisco re-branding Linksys gear as "Cisco" was one of the worst branding decisions they've made, as now they have their name associated with a *ton* of really crappy hardware. The SPAs are SIP-only, whereas AFAIK, you need SCCP-compatible devices to work with CME.

Comment: I thought it might boil down to SCCP / Skinny compatibility. Cisco branded SPA phones definitely don't support SCCP. I've got one at home.

Comment: The SPA's aren't even really Linksys devices - anyone noticed all the references to Sipura in all but the latest firmwares? Although to be pedantic you could say the same about the Call Manager phones actually being Selsius phones http://www.uccx.net/overview/one-really-old-ip-phone.html

Comment: It does strike me that the Cisco VOIP solution is more 'bolted together' rather than elegantly designed. It is very confusing having multiple incompatible offerings.

Comment: Find me something that's recent, cisco, and not bolted together.

Answer (score 0):

Actually thinking about it, I believe the 99xx phones are Callmanager but SIP only.

However the SPA's aren't supported and Call Manager will not be able to generate the correct xml provisioning files required.

Even if they were manually created, this post seems to sound like it won't work anyway http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/VoIP-Phones/Registering-SPA-942-to-CallManager-Express/td-p/28596